# Distinct lists on dates where an ID is present (i.e. intersects) on consecutive dates

Tags: sql, t-sql, set

I'm trying to make an MSSQL query that produces lists of apartment prices. The ultimate goal of the query is to calculate the percentage change in average prices of apartments. However, this final calculation (namely taking averages) is something I can fix in code provided that the list(s) of prices that are retrieved are correct.

What makes this tricky is that apartments are sold and new ones added all the time, so when comparing prices from week to week (I have weekly data), I only want to compare prices for apartments that have a recorded price in weeks `(t-1, t)`,  `(t, t+1)`, `(t+1,t+2)` etc. In other words, some apartments that had a recorded price in time `(t-1)` might not be there at time `t`, and some apartments may have been added at time `t` (and thus weren't there at time `t-1`). I only want to select prices in week `t-1` and `t` where some `ApartmentID` exists in both week  `t-1` and `t` to calculate the average change in week `t`.

Example data

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| RegistrationID | Date         | Price  | ApartmentID      |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| 1              | 2014-04-04   |   5    | 1                |
| 2              | 2014-04-04   |   6    | 2                |
| 3              | 2014-04-04   |   4    | 3                |
| 4              | 2014-04-11   |   5.2  | 1                |
| 5              | 2014-04-11   |   4    | 3                |
| 6              | 2014-04-11   |   7    | 4                |
| 7              | 2014-04-19   |   5.1  | 1                |
| 8              | 2014-04-19   |   4.1  | 3                |
| 9              | 2014-04-19   |   7.1  | 4                |
| 10             | 2014-04-26   |   4.1  | 3                |
| 11             | 2014-04-26   |   7.2  | 4                |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Solutions thoughts**

I think it makes sense to produce two different lists, one for odd-numbered weeks and one for even-numbered weeks. List 1 would then contain Date, Price and ApartmentID that are valid for the tuples `(t-1,t)`, `(t+1,t+2)`, `(t+3,t+4)` etc. while list 2 would contain the same for the tuples `(t,t+1)`,`(t+2,t+3)`,`(t+4,t+5)` etc. The reason I think two lists are needed is that for any given week `t`, there are two sets of apartments and corresponding prices that need to be produced - one that is "forward compatible" and one that is "backwards compatible".

If two such lists can be produced, then the rest is simply an exercise in taking averages over each distinct date.

I'm not really sure to begin here. I played a little around with `Intersect`, but I'm pretty sure I need to nest queries to get this to work.

**Result**

Using the methodology described above would yield two lists.

List 1:
Notice how RegistrationID 2 and 6 disappear because they don't exist in on both dates `2014-04-04` and `2014-04-11`. The same goes for RegistrationID 7 as this apartment doesn't exist for both `2014-04-19` and `2014-04-26`.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| RegistrationID | Date         | Price  | ApartmentID      |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| 1              | 2014-04-04   |   5    | 1                |
| 3              | 2014-04-04   |   4    | 3                |
| 4              | 2014-04-11   |   5.2  | 1                |
| 5              | 2014-04-11   |   4    | 3                |
| 8              | 2014-04-19   |   4.1  | 3                |
| 9              | 2014-04-19   |   7.1  | 4                |
| 10             | 2014-04-26   |   4.1  | 3                |
| 11             | 2014-04-26   |   7.2  | 4                |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

List 2:
Here, nothing disappears because every apartment is present in the tuples within the scope of this list.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| RegistrationID | Date         | Price  | ApartmentID      |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| 4              | 2014-04-11   |   5.2  | 1                |
| 5              | 2014-04-11   |   4    | 3                |
| 6              | 2014-04-11   |   7    | 4                |
| 7              | 2014-04-19   |   5.1  | 1                |
| 8              | 2014-04-19   |   4.1  | 3                |
| 9              | 2014-04-19   |   7.1  | 4                |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Edit your question with the results that you want from the sample data.

Comment: Could date by any day of the week, or will it always be the same day?  I realize in your data above that you have Friday (4/4 and 4/11) and Saturday (4/19 and 4/26) represented, but I wasn't sure if that was intentional or a typo.

Comment: @Jerrad It's intentional. Prices will only be recorded once per week but I can't guarantee that it's be on a mod 7 interval.

Comment: So if one price is on 4/5 (Saturday) and another is on 4/6 (Sunday), are those considered to be a week apart since they exist in two separate weeks (even though they are actually only 1 day apart)?

Comment: @Jerrad That'll never happen. I can guarantee that there will never be less than 5 days between records. However, using week number is in some sense a little misleading and isn't really central to the issue, though it may make it easier to solve to view the problem this way. It doesn't really matter to me where you "split" the week as long as it is consistent. A price will always appear within 7 days of the last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution.  First, I get all the records from the table (I named it "ApartmentPrice"), computing the WeekOf (which is the Sunday of that week), PreviousWeek (the Sunday of the previous week), and NextWeek (the Sunday of the following week).  I store that in a table variable (you could also put it in a CTE or a temp table).

```
declare @tempTable table(RegistrationId int, PriceDate date, Price decimal(8,2), ApartmentId int, WeekOf date, PreviousWeek date, NextWeek date)
Insert @tempTable
select ap.RegistrationId, 
ap.PriceDate,
ap.Price,
ap.ApartmentId,
DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,ap.PriceDate), 0) WeekOf, 
DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,dateadd(wk, -1, ap.PriceDate)), 0) PreviousWeek,
DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,dateadd(wk, 1, ap.PriceDate)), 0) NextWeek
from ApartmentPrice ap
```

Then I join that table variable to itself where WeekOf equals either NextWeek or PreviousWeek.  This gives the apartments that have a record in the adjoining week.

```
select distinct t.RegistrationId, t.PriceDate, t.Price, t.ApartmentId
from @tempTable t
join @tempTable t2 on t.ApartmentId = t2.ApartmentId and (t.WeekOf = t2.PreviousWeek or t.WeekOf = t2.NextWeek)
order by t.RegistrationId, t.ApartmentId, t.PriceDate
```

I'm using `distinct` because an apartment will appear more than once in the results if it does have an adjoining week record.

You can also find the average prices for each week like this:

```
select t.WeekOf, avg(distinct t.Price)
from @tempTable t
join @tempTable t2 on t.ApartmentId = t2.ApartmentId and (t.WeekOf = t2.PreviousWeek or t.WeekOf = t2.NextWeek)
group by t.WeekOf
order by t.WeekOf
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4606b/1/0).  I added a few more rows to the test data to show that it handles dates that cross the end of the year boundary.

Comment: Thanks! This is really close to a solution. I'm still convinced I need two individual tables though. When finding the % change from week t-1 to t only apartments that have records in both weeks. However, when finding from t to t+1, that may be a different set of apartments for period t than for the former interval. I've tried to use your solution as a basis for two individual tables but I'm still struggling. Any ideas for an amendment that could produce this?

Comment: Does this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4606b/11/0) help?  I modified the query to include a `NextPrevious` column.  It is `N` if the apartment had an entry in the next week, `P` if it had an entry in the previous week, and `NP` if it had both.